# im trying to make an api in flask that takes in 2 inputs

Tags: python, flask

ive got an api that takes in an id

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/books?id=u3qR4Ps4TbATrg97
```

looks like that

what im trying to do after that is add something to the end of the url, for example

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/books?id=u3qR4Ps4TbATrg97uid=something
```

im not 100% sure if this is possible

```
# Create some test data for our catalog in the form of a list of dictionaries.
books = [
    {'id': 'u3qR4Ps4TbATrg97',
     'uid': 'what',
     'title': 'A Fire Upon the Deep',
     'author': 'Vernor Vinge',
     'first_sentence': 'The coldsleep itself was dreamless.',
     'year_published': '1992'}
]

@app.route('/api/v1/resources/books', methods=['GET'])
def api_id():
    # Check if an ID was provided as part of the URL.
    # If ID is provided, assign it to a variable.
    # If no ID is provided, display an error in the browser.
    if 'id' and 'uid' in request.args:
        id = str(request.args['id'])
        uid = str(request.args['uid'])

    else:
        return "Error: No id field provided. Please specify an id."

    results = []

    for book in books:
        if book['id'] == id:
            results.append(book)
        if book['uid'] == uid:
            results.append(book)
```

this is what i have so far, mostly copy pasted from [here](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask)
thats no the whole file just the important bits i can think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two inputs inside the GET query like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/books?id=u3qR4Ps4TbATrg97&uid=something
```

Just put an & in between!

Comment: almost works 
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/books?id=u3qR4Ps4TbATrg97&uid=what`
thats the link i have now but i had to mess around with the for loop
[pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/BrZwXvX5)

Answer (score 1):

Use `request.args.get` method to get parameters from your url. Also add `&` to your URL as a parameter separator.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/v1/resources/books')
def books():
    id_ = request.args.get('id')
    uid = request.args.get('uid')
    return f'id: {id_}, uid: {uid}'

app.run()
```

Open http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/books?id=u3qR4Ps4TbATrg97&uid=something
in browser and you'll get:

```
id: u3qR4Ps4TbATrg97, uid: something
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple parameters|arguments are passed with `&` character. `?params1=5&params2=3`. For your example: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/books?id=u3qR4Ps4TbATrg97&uid=what`. For the code, I would do:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)
# Create some test data for our catalog in the form of a list of dictionaries.
books = [
    {
        "id": "u3qR4Ps4TbATrg97",
        "uid": "what",
        "title": "A Fire Upon the Deep",
        "author": "Vernor Vinge",
        "first_sentence": "The coldsleep itself was dreamless.",
        "year_published": "1992",
    }
]


@app.route("/api/v1/resources/books", methods=["GET"])
def api_id():
    # Check if an ID was provided as part of the URL.
    # If ID is provided, assign it to a variable.
    # If no ID is provided, display an error in the browser.

    
    if set(["id","uid"]).intersection(set(request.args)):
        id_ = str(request.args["id"])
        uid = str(request.args["uid"])

    else:
        return make_response(
            jsonify({"message": "Error: No id field provided. Please specify an id."}),
            400,
        )

    results = []

    for book in books:
        if book["id"] == id_:
            results.append(book)
        if book["uid"] == uid:
            results.append(book)

    response = make_response(
        jsonify({"message": results}),
        200,
    )
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    return response
```

This would return status code 400 if no match and 200 when match